# How to use Integrated Graphics as gpu and dedicated graphics as only display output ..?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, gpu, vga

I have intel i5 4460 with HD4600 and dedicated GPU of gt710 The only reason I bought the card was to get HDMI display output as my motherboard only as VGA output but now it seems like gt710 is slower than my integrated graphics so is there any way to use internal graphics as the primary GPU and use my gt710 only for display output I know I could connect VGA but the VGA port in my monitor is dead Please Tell Any Solutions...
Thank You

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Instead of continuing to pile on downvotes, maybe explain what you think is wrong with the question.

Comment: @DanielB I think my answer does just that.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an adapter to convert from VGA to HDMI, to use exclusively
the integrated graphics adapter. This is much cheaper than adding
a GPU, so perhaps you could get reimbursed for the gt710.

A random example from Amazon is
[this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06X3ZVJ2K)
(this is *not* a recommendation.)

Answer (score -1):

> it seems like gt710 is slower than my integrated graphics

The benchmarks tell a completely different story - https://technical.city/en/video/GeForce-GT-710-vs-HD-Graphics-4600 - and this is expected. Even for contemporary and with similar performance graphics (contemporary yes; performance not even close), the discrete Nvidia wins hands down in any test and the dedicated memory discrete cards have (vs. the system reserved memory all integrated graphics must "steal" from the system) automatically translate to superior performance.

If yours is performing worse than the old Intel HD4600 then there are a few hypotheses (most can't be fixed, obviously):

- Software/drivers problem - Make sure to install the latest Nvidia driver that supports your card (v. 474.xx for Windows 10/11; v. 470.xxx for Linux)
- Defective card - replace it
- FAKE - Get your money back if you can.